# Does not WSO2 Choreo Connect supports gRPC?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a few questions about the latest WSO2 product(APIM, Choreo Connect). Even referring to the official documentation, there were parts that I couldn't find. So I leave you a question.

1. Does WSO2 Choreo Connect 1.0.0 not support gRPC?
   Microgateway 3.2.0 supports gRPC, so it was possible to use gRPC with APIM 3.x.
   However, the latest version of Microgateway, Choreo Connect, doesn't seem to support gRPC.
   Is there a roadmap for gRPC in the near future?
2. Can't Choreo Connect 1.0.0 be deployed on-premises?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Choreo Connect does not support gRPC APIs at the moment. It is in the roadmap.
2. You have to use Kubernetes to deploy Choreo Connect. Although it is not hard bound to K8s at the moment, in the future it can be. So it is highly recommended to use K8s to deploy CC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
It seems not to support grpc in 1.2.0. 
Is it long term roadmap?